# Add None dimension in Tensorflow 2 shape

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to change

```
Tensorshape(60, 60, 64)
```

into

```
Tensorshape(None, 60, 60, 64)
```

I'm using it in a model and the dimension None is used for batch I think.

I can have

```
Tensorshape(1, 60, 60, 64)
```

but it means I have a batch size = 1 (it's works with batch_size = 1 but not with other values)

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal example where you think you need this. `None` just denotes a dimension of variable length. A tensor of shape `60 x 60 x 64` cannot get a `None` axis because you cannot change the number of elements, so only axes of size 1 can be added.